# Software center and Command Line

Tags: installation, command-line, software-center

Can somebody explain me what is "Install it from Software Center", and "install from a command line" please?. I was using another OS and only two days on Ubuntu.Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The software center is a tool which allows you to view all software packages held in the ubuntu repository in a graphical user interface. It's the utility which looks like this:

[image: software center]

On the other hand, installation by command line uses tools such as `apt-get install` to install packages. While the same packages are found in the command line installation utilities and the software center, the use of the terminal allows packages to be installed in situations like on servers where GUI's aren't present.

Comment: Thank you so much, jackweirdy.So my friend, do I have to use either software center or command line in all installations? I am asking this because that I installed Skype to Ubuntu 12.04,directly from the download link as I did in windows,and now Skype is installed but cannot get the log in screen in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: The software centre is great for most installations, but many closed-source packages, skype included, aren't present on in the software center. To install skype you _do_ have to download from the skype website. It sounds like the problem you're having is skype specific, try asking a new question or try looking at [the skype support network](http://community.skype.com)

Comment: No problem :) good to hear

Comment: @jackweirdy : softwares found in software center maynot available in command line , Eg: paid apps , and closed source apps submitted through myapps portal