# how i can install any program with terminal

Tags: command-line, system-installation, installed-programs

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 now in my computer 
but the problem is the Ubuntu software can't download any apps.

So the solution is to install the any program with terminal
but I don't now how ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu), [How to install software provided in software-center via terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/268504/how-to-install-software-provided-in-software-center-via-terminal) and [Software center and Command Line](http://askubuntu.com/questions/136031/software-center-and-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing via terminal is usually using `apt` or `apt-get`.

First of all you need to know what package should be installed, therefor you need to know the package-name.

Assuming you want to install thunderbird you would first of all search for the package name like this

```
apt search thunderbird
```

This should output a huge list of packages - locate the proper package ayou are looking for - in our case its simple `thunderbird`.

Now install the package like this

```
sudo apt install thunderbird
```

Finally - i do prefer commandline to install software, but you could as well search for a solution for your base problem - the non working **Ubuntu Software** application. Therefor it could be helpful to start this software from terminal to get some error-output which could help finding a solution.